# Unexpected "never" in Typescript

Tags: typescript

So I'm trying to loop over properties of an object.

```js
interface IProperties {
    foo?: {
        foo?: string[]
        bar?: string[]
    }
}

function init(properties: IProperties) {
    if (properties.foo) {
        for (const [key] of Object.entries(properties.foo)) {
            const prop = key as keyof typeof properties.foo

            if (properties.foo[prop].length) {
                properties.foo[prop] = properties.foo[prop].trim()
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I'm getting the error message "Property 'length' does not exist on type 'never'".
Apparently the "prop" variable is expected to never have a value, but I can't understand why it does that.

---

EDIT:

Here's the [TypeScript Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgJIAUoHsAO0zAQDOyA3gFACQMWWA-AFxlXW2PJFhSgDmA2gF0WAIzhR2nbiH5DKAX3ILyMAK4gEBLCGShgYABQ5seKAWJMMx-ISIBKZpWAxkhq6ZsA6GlnsVKrKBcELU5kPgBrCABPAWQsZwB5YQArCA0PCHBuYldca2IvWltfFkpgkFCjXGQAXmRIqOQ4Egb45DAovDaqkzMiQqxyUqcXHvz+7z4egQ8AG0yeMAALEv9-MfcCyena5A2+ganjGa5gAFt9W1KFfxuFOSA)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

### Problem

First, we need to note the following points-

The `keyof` operator returns `never` if the type is "nullable" or can be `undefined`

```js
type Keys = keyof ({a: string} | undefined)
// type of Keys is never
```

Next, inside the block of `if`, `properties.foo` is now not-undefined i.e. it's type is narrow-downed to exclude `undefined`. But it loses it's narrowness in the inner scope of the loop (https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/30576).

Ergo, while evaluation the type of `keyof typeof properties.foo`, `properties.foo` includes `undefined`. So, the type assertion resolves to `never`.

### Solution

There are two possible solutions-

1. Use [`NonNullable`](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/utility-types.html#nonnullabletype) in the loop

```js
const prop = key as keyof NonNullable<typeof properties.foo>
```

[Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ssl=11&ssc=73&pln=11&pc=13#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgJIAUoHsAO0zAQDOyA3gFDJXIxZYD8AXGZdW7Q80WFKAOYBtALqs2VAEZwoTZN14hBItgF9yq8jACuIBASwhkoYGAAUObHigFizDBfyEiAShZtgMZGftXHAOg4uFGLUtFCeCPrcyAIA1hAAnkLIWB4A8uIAVhC6vhDgvMReuA7E-nROgaLB1BEgUea4yAC8yHHxyHAkbSnIAHL6vZoANkNw4kMQADxg8Xg9DZbWRGVYAHzkVdWGHkWLfhwCC0L0vhMKYAAWlVtbAPS3yAAqqQAiqcwwwAAeyJco4hAhlgAO7IIagCAAGmQCxKywOR0MJAABgBBKBQODxZGbG5Ue7IZE8YAAW2RyAAJlhiMgQFgwMgIF9gNwSPpCejMdjcXiCbCfKUERYki1+UsVodhb5iSSTE4eWJVFsldRVMogA)

2. Move the type resolution in the `if` block.

```js
interface IProperties {
    foo?: {
        foo?: string[]
        bar?: string[]
    }
}

function init(properties: IProperties) {
    if (properties.foo) {
        type Keys = keyof typeof properties.foo
        for (const [key] of Object.entries(properties.foo)) {
            const prop = key as Keys

            if (properties.foo[prop]?.length) {
                // TODO: fix the below line, properties.foo[prop] is `Array`
                // `trim` does not exists on `Array`
                // properties.foo[prop] = properties.foo[prop].trim()
            }
        }
    }
}
```

[Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ssl=1&ssc=1&pln=21&pc=2#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgJIAUoHsAO0zAQDOyA3gFDJXIxZYD8AXGZdW7Q80WFKAOYBtALqs2VAEZwoTZN14hBItgF9yq8jACuIBASwhkoYGAAUObHigFizDBfyEiAShZtgMZGftXHAOg4uFGLUYACeeMgA0hChJAC8yADWMVgeYXipyOa4DsT+dKJitFCeCPrcyALJoULImQDy4gBWELq+EOC8xF45PnkBgYXBVGUgFdk4yAnVyHAk0bHkQ8PunhO5RPlYAhNC9L4ANh18YAAWg8OXyAD018gAKvUAIvXMMMAAHshnKOIQB1gAO7IA6gCAAGiy3msmw4OwstWAJAABgBBKBQOChZHLK43O7InjAAC2yOQABMsMRkCAsGBkBAPkiwCR9Mg0RisTi8cFblDejCtvDcLUEus+rC6MKcEJfETiSYnLixKpLqrqKplEA)

---

In my opinion, the best practice is to create type on where other types lie, not in the function definition.

```js
interface IProperties {
    foo?: {
        foo?: string[]
        bar?: string[]
    }
}

type IPropertiesFooKeys = keyof NonNullable<IProperties['foo']>

function init(properties: IProperties) {
    if (properties.foo) {
        for (const [key] of Object.entries(properties.foo)) {
            const prop = key as IPropertiesFooKeys

            if (properties.foo[prop]?.length) {
                // TODO: fix the below line, properties.foo[prop] is `Array`
                // `trim` does not exists on `Array`
                // properties.foo[prop] = properties.foo[prop].trim()
            }
        }
    }
}
```

[Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ssl=1&ssc=1&pln=22&pc=2#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgJIAUoHsAO0zAQDOyA3gFDJXIxZYD8AXGZdW7Q80WFKAOYBtALqs2VAEZwoTZN14hBItgF9yq8mACeeNJlz5CRAGJ0A0hE0kAvMgDWFrDGQA5LCGcBXADZe44rxAAPBjYeFAExAIA5BxRQgB85OQwHiAIBG7IoMBgABQ4oQbEzCH64YYAlCxswE75heXEAHQcVRRi1LRQyLkIbtzIAvaaQsiOyADy4gBWEOlNEOC8xPVlEUQtdBVtoh3UfSADBbjINsPIcCSlYesmWOaWSXtitT3HN4abWALvQvRNAQUYAAFjtns8APQQ5AAFQmABEJswYMAAB7IEEocQQLxYADuyC8oAgABpkO8ihsOD9QqNgCQAAYAQSgUDgmgZu3B1ChyAZPGAAFsGcgACZYYjIEBYMDICCo+lgEiZZms9mc7kdXkUxpUug03CjGw69ZfA04IRNAWC3IVLl7VTPR3UVTKIA)

Comment: Third solution is to define the keys of your object https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgJIAUoHsAO0zAQDOyA3gFDJXIxZYD8AXGZdW7Q80WFKAOYBtALqs2VAEZwoTZN14hBItgF9yq8jACuIBASwhkoYGAAUObHigFizDBfyEiAShZtgMZGftXHAOg4uFGLUtFCeCPrcyADWEACeyFgeAPLiAFYQur6xcUReuA7E-nROgaLB1BEgUea4yAC8MfHIcCQARBxtyAA+yG2SUG0A3OUVyFVRAG5wADaaKI21ltZExVgCS0IjY24eJtNzKACEjdoAJhAwoBBnZTsVE2DIMxAGjQfzvi8KYAAW2-dkKoxsDqKpVEA

Comment: @AmirSaleem, nope, that's just a workaround. The OP may need to add other properties in future, which will make it unfeasible.

Comment: Yup, agreed with you.

Comment: Both of the solutions above worked for the issue I mentioned. However, no matter how many if-statements I run to check that the property actually exists, it always throw the error "Object is possibly 'undefined'".
https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgJIAUoHsAO0zAQDOyA3gFACQMWWA-AFxlXW2PJFhSgDmA2gF0WAIzhR2nbiH5DKAX3ILyMAK4gEBLCGShgYABQ5seKAWJMMx-ISIBKZpWAxkhq6ZsA6GlnsVKrKBcELU5kPgBrCABPAWQsZwB5YQArCA0PCHBuYldca2IvWltfFkpgkFCjXGQAXmRIqOQ4Egb45AA5LXaVABseuGEeiAAeMCi8NqqTMyJCrAA+clKnFyn82e8+KYE6DyHpMAALEv9-GkD9ctDJOOc19wLN7ZPTygB6N7RIKDgCaVL5KUFP5gQo5EA

Comment: @ShivamSingla The link you posted was about handlers. You don't know when the handler will be called. So I wonder why the problem occurs here.

Comment: @JonathanNielsen Use [`Non-null assertion operator`](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-2-0.html#non-null-assertion-operator) - [Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgJIAUoHsAO0zAQDOyA3gFACQMWWA-AFxlXW2PJFhSgDmA2gF0WAIzhR2nbiH5DKAX3ILyMAK4gEBLCGShgYABQ5seKAWJMMx-ISIBKZpWAxkhq6ZsA6GlnsVKrKBcELU5kPgBrCABPAWQsZwB5YQArCA0PCHBuYldca2IvWltfFkpgkFCjXGQAXmRIqOQ4Egb45AA5LXaVABseuGEeiAAeMCi8NqqTMyJCrAA+clKnFyn82e8+KYE6DyHpMAALEv9-GkD9ctDJOOc19wLN7YBCE9PKAHoP5Hf3gD0-s8AchSv4vmhIFA4ARpKCFKd4fIqAo5EA)

Comment: @jperl Yes, it was all that I could find closest. Please edit the post with the exact issue if it exists.

Comment: I'll just mark the issue as resolved since the issue described here is resolved.
I'll keep researching a bit myself, I'll open another issue if I can't solve the rest by myself. Thank you for the help!