# Scoping rules for undefined type guard in Typescript

Tags: typescript

I've been playing with the code in question [Unexpected "never" in Typescript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66814161/unexpected-never-in-typescript)

I am trying to understand the undefined guard, and assumed that the variable is inferred to be not null / undefined in the scope of entire block following the check.

```
interface IProperties {
    foo?: {
        aaa: string
        bbb: string
    }
}

function init(properties: IProperties) {
    if (properties.foo) {
        type FooOK = typeof properties.foo;  
        for (const x of [1, 2, 3]) {
          type FooOrUndefined = typeof properties.foo;
        }
    } 
}
```

The types are inferred as follows:

```
type FooOK = { aaa: string; bbb: string;}
type FooOrUndefined = { aaa: string; bbb: string;} | undefined
```

Could anyone explain why the type in the loop does not take the guard into account?

[Playground link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgJIAUoHsAO0zAQDOyA3gFDJXIxZYD8AXGZdW3B80WFKAOas2VAEaiuPfoOQBfcrPIwAriAQEsIZKGBgAFDmx4oBYswwH8hIgEoWbYDGR7zRywDpaWGxSHUwATzxkADE6AHkAaWQAXmR-PCwHfVwLYnc6AG4pNlooRwR1bmQAD2QE5ABtAEYAGmQAJlqAZgBdLyyhOJQQrFCoAFUQABMIGFAIQejYgIgypMNjIjSsTJ8qWTZpZDlyIA)

Comment: Someone literally just asked a question about it a few minutes ago https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66814161/unexpected-never-in-typescript

Comment: @jperl I think it's different, even if it uses a similar structure as `IProperties`

Comment: @jperl I added the link to the original question, I was playing with one with the answers and run across the probem I described, which is not directly explained in thet squestion. I think mine is a bit more specific, hence a new question.

Comment: @Lesiak your question is actually vastly different. It's fine as a new question. Interestingly, it's assigning to a `type` that seems to be affecting it - if you just look at `properties.foo` it's correctly narrowed to just `{ aaa: string; bbb: string; }` both before and after the loop. [See here](https://tsplay.dev/Nl0DeN). I can't explain it but it's interesting.

Comment: No worries, I didn't mark as a duplicate. You identified the root cause problem and it may stand alone as a question. On the other thread, someone posted a link to an issue with handlers. But I can't see how that is relevant to our specific issue. I understand that handlers (callbacks) are called at a later time.

Comment: @VLAZ I opened a bug for it: https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/43411

Comment: @Lesiak this bug is eerily reminiscent of another one [I've commented on](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/10530#issuecomment-603915317). Yet, I am totally not sure if they are related and *how*. The other one is about bracket notation not really working when type guarding. But in this case there is 1. no bracket notation 2. the type guard works *at first*, just somehow stops working in a `type` declaration.